# Get value of multiple checkbox & echo in email

Tags: php, email, checkbox

Getting trouble on adding multiple checkbox value within mail body due to my low knowledge in PHP.

I know that it possible to show/`echo` checkbox by array with `foreach` loop but i don't know to `echo` it within mail body. I want to echo it within `$message`.

HTML Code sample-

```
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]"  value="Value1"> Title1
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]"  value="Value2"> Title2
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]"  value="Value3"> Title3
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]"  value="Value4"> Title4
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]"  value="Value5"> Title5
```

PHP Code-

```
<?php

$to = "arifkpi@gmail.com";
$fromEmail = "arif@arif-khan.net";
$fromName = "Arif Khan";
$subject = "Contact Email";
$message = "Hey, Someone Sent you a Contact Message through your Website.

    Details Below-      
    Name: $_POST[fname] $_POST[lname]
    Email Address: $_POST[email]
    Contact Number: $_POST[contact1] $_POST[contact2] $_POST[contact3]
    Zip Code: $_POST[zip]
    Best Time To Contact: $_POST[besttime]
    Payment Plan Options: $_POST[payment_plan]
    MUA: $_POST[mua]
    Shoot Concept:
    Shoot Concept(Other): $_POST[shootother]";

$headers = "From:" . $fromName . " " . $fromEmail;

$flgchk = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers"); 
if($flgchk){
echo "A email has been sent to: $to";
}
else{
echo "Error in Email sending";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do,

```
$colors = isset($_POST['color']) ? implode(",",$_POST['color']) : '';
```

And now you can use this `$colors` (you will get all selected colors as comma separeted) in your email message body part.

```
$message = "Hey, Someone Sent you a Contact Message through your Website.

Details Below-      
Name: $_POST[fname] $_POST[lname]
Colors: $colors
Email Address: $_POST[email]
Contact Number: $_POST[contact1] $_POST[contact2] $_POST[contact3]
Zip Code: $_POST[zip]
Best Time To Contact: $_POST[besttime]
Payment Plan Options: $_POST[payment_plan]
MUA: $_POST[mua]
Shoot Concept:
Shoot Concept(Other): $_POST[shootother]";
```

Comment: how can i implement it with $message, i want it in mail body. Thanks

Comment: see my updated answer, I have added `$colors` in message body.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/arifkpi/public_html/arif/project/cform/form_action.php on line 8                         Line 8- $color= isset($_POST['color']) = implode(", ",$_POST['color']) : '';

Comment: Just update but new error, Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/arifkpi/public_html/arif/project/cform/form_action.php on line 8

Comment: Can you post output of `$_POST['color']` ?

Comment: In that I can't see any field with name `color`. Have you added colors multi-check box in your html ?

Comment: I use shoot[] there instead of color[] & same on php page too

Comment: Yes, did it but error. Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/arifkpi/public_html/arif/project/cform/form_action.php on line 8

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51089/discussion-between-rikesh-and-arifix)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(isset($_POST['color'])) {
    $message.= implode(',', $_POST['color']);
}
```

Comment: Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/arifkpi/public_html/arif/project/cform/form_action.php on line 22         Your code is on line 22